# Detect order of applications, windows, tabs

Tags: applescript

I'm using AppleScript to find all tabs in multiple browsers (testing on Safari first) with certain criteria in it's title and give it to `stdout` for another script.

So I have the basic information I need;

`window` `id`

`tab` `index`

`tab` `name`

`tab` `visible`

So from this point I know which of my Safari screens are matching my criteria and I log their `window` `id` and their `tab` `index`. Besides that with `tab` `visible` I can know which is the foremost one.

Now I still have one issue. I really want to be able to know which window and tab was the last one active. Even if I can only know the `window` `id` that was used last by the user it would automatically mean that inside that window the `tab` with `visible` true is the last one.

But there is one more thing. If the `visible` `tab` is not meeting my criteria, then I would still need to know the order of the last active one too.

So what I'm looking for is an counter/order value of the last active windows and tabs. I can't find something in the documentation that could give me that counter. For example; the TAB-logic in OS X knows which apps were last used. I was wondering if that logic would be available as some kind of system variable and then also on it's window/tab sub level.

My code (slimmed down does this):

```
tell application "Safari"
    ...
    repeat with win in winlist
       ...
       repeat with t in tablets
           # win.id
           # t.index
           # t.name
           # t.visible
       end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

And so I'm looking for something that emulates `win`.`lastUsedOrderIndex` and `t`.`lastUsedOrderIndex`.

Comment: Be aware that browsers have different AppleScript dictionaries. For example FireFox has none at all.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm gonna focus on Safari/Chrome first tho. Any browser that won't comply I'm gonna skip first. Maybe I'll try to write extensions for incompatible browsers later.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that if you do not find the properties you need in the application's dictionary, then you are out of luck. Window and Document lists in AppleScript are normally in a front-to-back ordering, since they are based on the `orderedWindows` and `orderedDocuments` NSArrays. Tabs in a browser are probably ordered left-to-right or right-to-left, based on the language localization, but I would be surprised if any browser had a reason to return tabs ordered by when they were "last used", whatever that means.